# #selector for class protocole error in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, selector

I need the selector for some of the UIWebViewDelegate
In objective-C we get it like this:
This is an example with more than 1 parameter :

```
@selector(webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)
```

This is an example with only one parameter :

```
@selector(webViewDidStartLoad:)
```

How to get it in swift? , how to translate the same code to swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is like so

Selector for methods with more than one paramater

In Objective-C :

```
@selector(webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)
```

In Swift:

`#selector(UIWebViewDelegate.webView(_:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:))`

Selector for methods with one paramater

In Objective-C :

```
@selector(webViewDidStartLoad:)
```

In Swift :

```
#selector(UIWebViewDelegate.webViewDidStartLoad(_:))
```